# Recovering ID of a specific image

Tags: jquery

How can I get the ID of an image according to the following situation

**JQUERY**

```
$(".favoritar").click(function (data) {
    // Here I want recover the previous IMG ID, that in this case should be
    // DannaWhite, but the following code returns <img src="../../fotos_teste/05.PNG" id="DannaWhite" width="50" height="50" />
    alert($(this).parent().closest(".bxFotoUsuarioLateral").html());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #0F4265 !important;">
    <div class="bxFotoUsuarioLateral">
        <img src="../../fotos_teste/05.PNG" id="DannaWhite" width="50" height="50" />
    </div>

    <div class="icon-star"></div>     

    <img src="../../Images/favorito.png" class="favoritar" id="favoritarPost1" style="float: right; cursor: pointer;" />
    <h4 class="modal-title" style="margin-left: 70px;">Cancelamento de Contrato <span id="idImovelAlteraStatus"></span></h4>
    <span class="txtSample05" style="text-transform: none; margin-left: 40px;">Há 2 horas</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).prop('id')`?

Comment: No, I'm in the click action of the class .favoritar, the image that I want its before

Comment: Ok, `$(this).closest('div.modal-header').find('.bxFotoUsuarioLateral > img').prop('id')`. If there are more than one image in the div you can `.map()` the ids and get an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(this).closest(".modal-header").find(".bxFotoUsuarioLateral img").attr("id");
```

or

```
$(this).parents(".modal-header").find(".bxFotoUsuarioLateral img").attr("id");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YB9Vw/)**

Comment: Also, use `prop('id')`

Comment: @mplungjan: hey thanks. i was stucked making fiddle. Thanks for catch. fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one image:

```
var id = $(this).closest('div.modal-header')
                .find('.bxFotoUsuarioLateral > img').prop('id');
```

If you want an array of ids, regardless of the amount of images:

```
var ids = $(this).closest('div.modal-header')
                .find('.bxFotoUsuarioLateral > img')
                .map(function(){
                    return this.id;
                }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/arpankamal/8uZNd/2/)

```
$(".favoritar").click(function (data) {
  // Here I want recover the previous IMG ID, that in this case should be
  // DannaWhite, but the following code returns undefined
  alert( $(this).parents(".modal-header").find(".bxFotoUsuarioLateral img").attr("id"))
});
```